# Creating a renewable kerberos ticket using jdk kinit on windows

Tags: windows, kerberos

I am trying to create a renewable kerberos ticket using kinit on the windows command line. This is an example of the command and parameters I am using:

```
%JAVA_HOME%\bin\kinit.exe -r "99999d" -k -t <<path_to_my_keytab>> <<my_principal>>
```

However, this fails with the following error:

```
kinit.exe : Exception: too many parameters
```

As far as I can tell I have followed the syntax described in the documentation at:

https://web.mit.edu/kerberos/krb5-1.12/doc/user/user_commands/kinit.html

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Note that the link you reference is for MIT Kerberos, not JDK Kerberos. There's no guarantee they share the same parameters. JDK docs suggest v11 supports the -r parameter, but v7 does not.

Comment: thanks a lot @Steve  - that explains it